# Grid Arrange mutliple ggplots from evaluated text

Tags: r, ggplot2, eval

I am trying to `grid.arrange()` several ggplots which I need to call/evaluate from a string of text. However, I am failing miserably - only the last plot is plotted (`p4` in the example case below).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
p <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt, color = cyl))

p1 <- p + geom_point()
p2 <- p + geom_histogram()
p3 <- p + geom_dotplot()
p4 <- p + geom_smooth(method='lm')

tx <- paste0("p", 1:4)

grid.arrange(grobs = list(eval(parse(text = tx))), nrow = 2)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making use of `lapply` this could be achieved like so:

Note: To make `geom_histogram` and `geom_dotplot` work I made `y = wt` a local aes for both the `geom_point` and `geom_smooth` as otherwise your code resulted in an error.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
p <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, color = cyl))

p1 <- p + geom_point(aes(y = wt))
p2 <- p + geom_histogram()
p3 <- p + geom_dotplot()
p4 <- p + geom_smooth(aes(y = wt), method='lm')

tx <- paste0("p", 1:4)

grid.arrange(grobs = lapply(tx, function(x) eval(parse(text = x))), nrow = 2)
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> `stat_bindot()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]